# Howto install google-mock on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, programming, c++, testing

I am having hard time trying to install Google C++ Mocking Framework. I have successfully run `sudo apt-get install google-mock`. Then I tried to compile this sample file

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

with `g++ -lgmock main.cpp` and these errors have shown

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleMock(int*, char**)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess the linker can not find the library files. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I've now successfully started using gmock by building my own version as per the README provided with the source download from googlemock project website.

Get the download zip from the website:
http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/downloads/list

Unzip this to a directory, say `${GMOCK_ROOT}`. Then, as per **README instructions**:

```
cd ${GMOCK_ROOT}
mkdir build
cd build
g++ -I../gtest/include -I../gtest -I../include -I.. -c ../gtest/src/gtest-all.cc
g++ -I../gtest/include -I../gtest -I../include -I.. -c ../src/gmock-all.cc
ar -rv libgmock.a gtest-all.o gmock-all.o
```

Thus you have your own libgmock.a in `${GMOCK_ROOT}/build`. You actually also need pthreads to compile, so your compile command after that becomes:

```
g++ -I${GMOCK_ROOT}/include/ main.cpp -L${GMOCK_ROOT}/build -lgmock -lpthread
```

Comment: Confirmed that it works. Goog job! I just wonder why is the order of g++'s parameters important.

Answer (score 5):

*libgmock-dev* will be included in the default Ubuntu 18.10 repositories, Otherwise in earlier Ubuntu releases you have to manually download and install it.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmock-dev
cd /usr/src/googletest/googlemock/
sudo mkdir build
sudo cmake ..
sudo make
sudo cp googlemock/*.a /usr/lib
```

Comment: make sure you add detailed explanation of what you are suggesting the user tries.

Answer (score 2):

To give context to Pavel's answer, the compiled Google Mock binary is not distributed with the Ubuntu package because of the reason given [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog). This explanation is for Google Test, but the principle applies to any C++ library.

Specifically, it says:

> In the early days, we said that you could install compiled Google Test
>   libraries on *nix systems using make install. Then every user of your
>   machine can write tests without recompiling Google Test.
>
> This seemed like a good idea, but it has a got-cha: every user needs
>   to compile his tests using the same compiler flags used to compile the
>   installed Google Test libraries; otherwise he may run into undefined
>   behaviors (i.e. the tests can behave strangely and may even crash for
>   no obvious reasons).
>
> Why? Because C++ has this thing called the One-Definition Rule: if two
>   C++ source files contain different definitions of the same
>   class/function/variable, and you link them together, you violate the
>   rule. The linker may or may not catch the error (in many cases it's
>   not required by the C++ standard to catch the violation). If it
>   doesn't, you get strange run-time behaviors that are unexpected and
>   hard to debug.
>
> If you compile Google Test and your test code using different compiler
>   flags, they may see different definitions of the same
>   class/function/variable (e.g. due to the use of #if in Google Test).
>   Therefore, for your sanity, we recommend to avoid installing
>   pre-compiled Google Test libraries. Instead, each project should
>   compile Google Test itself such that it can be sure that the same
>   flags are used for both Google Test and the tests.

So your original problem was because installing the `google-mock` package only installed the source code, and when you tried to compile your sample application, no gmock library could be found.

Comment: I wonder why is this so. There are many C++ libraries that work precompiled inside /lib.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 'gmock' and everything related to its installation. I work with two folders '/tmp' and '/gmock', when absent 'gmock' i get:

```
Could NOT find GMock  (missing: GMOCK_LIBRARY GMOCK_MAIN_LIBRARY)
Configuring done
Generating done
```

for install gmock:

```
# snap install --classic cmake
# apt install g++
# export PATH="/snap/bin:$PATH"
# VERSION='1.7.0'
# INSTALL_DIR='/usr/local'
# mkdir ~/.mydownload && DOWNLOAD_DIR='~/.mydownload'
# cd ~/.mydownload
# GTEST_TARFILE="gtest-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
# GTEST_DIR='gtest'
# wget -O $GTEST_TARFILE https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-${VERSION}.tar.gz
# tar xzvf $GTEST_TARFILE
# mv googletest-release-${VERSION} $GTEST_DIR
# GMOCK_TARFILE="gmock-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
# GMOCK_DIR="gmock"
# wget -O $GMOCK_TARFILE https://github.com/google/googlemock/archive/release-${VERSION}.tar.gz
# tar xzvf $GMOCK_TARFILE
# mv googlemock-release-${VERSION} $GMOCK_DIR
# cd ~/.mydownload/gmock
# cmake .
# make
# mkdir -p ${INSTALL_DIR}/include
# cp -r include/gmock ${INSTALL_DIR}/include
# cp -r ../${GTEST_DIR}/include/gtest ${INSTALL_DIR}/include
# mkdir -p ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib
# cp *.a ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib
# cp gtest/*.a ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib
# cd /home/user
# rm -r ~/.mydownload
```

after these commands i see what 'gmock' is found:

```
Found GMock: /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a
Configuring done
Generating done
```